# Django won't run after connecting MySQL database

Tags: python, django, database, libreoffice, assertions

When I enter:

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

into my usual folder I am given the following output:

```
C:\Users\user\projects\steveone\steveone>python manage.py runserver Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py", line 5, in <module>
    import subprocess

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in <module>
    import threading

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\threading.py", line 10, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
    import linecache

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\linecache.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tokenize

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\sre_compile.py", line 18, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"

AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
```

I am not running a virtualenv (I know), and this only started happening after I connected LibreOffice to MySQL via JBDC today. From what I have gathered, I have a feeling that it might have to do with the path, but I am not really sure. I am fairly new to web development but up until this point I have been able to find answers to the problems that I have faced. I had it up and running yesterday and this has only happened since after I was fiddling with the database.

Edit 1: I have tried the suggestion to reinstall anaconda, but the error still persists. I get the same error as before.

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/619

Comment: I tried re installing anaconda but that never worked, the same error exists when I try runserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a couple of days and some nerdrage, I have found a solution.

I uninstalled django, anaconda, and python in that order.

I reinstalled anaconda and django in that order.

This made the python.exe in my anaconda folder my primary python application. (?)

I then added:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
>   into my Path in system environment variables.

After this I tried to run the app with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but I got the error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000147B66DEAE8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 26, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?

C:\Users\Kevin\projects\steveone\steveone> Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
'Error' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Kevin\projects\steveone\steveone>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002889B6AEAE8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 26, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

I tried using

`pip install MySQL-python`

but that was giving me

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Kevin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_yvqinya\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpy1lf3g11pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Kevin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_yvqinya\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-w7u4ethq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

So I first tried to fix that through various methods, all which failed.
including updating setup tools and wheel:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel
```

and running the msi installer:

> mysql-connector-python-2.1.7-py3.4-windows-x86-64bit

which failed (both ways described in the docs).

So I decided to attempt to achieve the connection through Mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Which fixed the problem and now the app runs.

In closing, I can only speculate as to what the problems were, If anyone reads this and has some thoughts in retrospect then I would love to hear them.